# ADF v2 Copy Activity, Log details about activity to Database Table

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there an option to Log details of Copy Activity to a Database Table.
I want to log the FileName & PAth that was generate, PipelineID that Generated it, How long it took to copy the File, Rows it copied, size of File Created plus few more.

How can all of these be achieved ?

Comment: You want to do this with .net or rest api or powershell?

Comment: .net or rest api preferably as long as i get most of the details i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could reference this two link.
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically

The first one is about what information you can get. The second is to tell you how to get these information with different way.

But currently, I don’t think there is a way to get file name and path directly. But you could leverage user properties. Please reference this post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8692cd00-307b-4204-a547-bed2030cb762/adfv2-user-property-setting?forum=AzureDataFactory